# How to configure intellij to recognize my media directory

Tags: django, intellij-idea

I'm working in a django project and i would like to make Intellij-IDEA resolve the path of my media folders(css/imgs/js)

this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/projectname/css/main.css">
```

give me the error:
Cannot resolve directory 'media'

Is there any way to configure it?

Comment: Is it located in your module root? If not, you can try adding more Content Roots to the module so that this directory appears in the root.

Comment: No, it isn't in my content root, is there another advantage to set it as one of my content roots?

Comment: Code completion will work better.